# Pokemons does not appear while being abroad

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm a Spanish user with iPhone who is travelling abroad. While being in Japan I noticed that the official app was available on the Apple App Store, so I downloaded the game, registered and started an account.

First set of 3 pokemons to choose appear correctly and choosed one of them. Since that, I connected many other times and walked around a little (usually within the wifi range I was connecting through) and never saw any other Pokemon. In addition, I have never seen any pokestop or gym in the map.

Does this makes sense? If I can see the game on the App Store means that I'm able to play, so what's wrong? Also I tried to connect through a vpn to Spain and still didn't work.

Any idea of what is going on?
Thanks in advance!

Edit to address the "possible duplicate question" pointed by @Frank:

The accepted answer in the other question states that you can play the game if the servers of the country you are visiting allows you.

In my case it seems like the servers allow me since I can login and play, but pokemons never appear, so I guess it's a different issue. Besides that, the accepted answer also points to use a VPN which I explained I tried without success.